# Освободится ли память по смещённому указателю?

Tags: c, память, malloc, free

```
char *data = malloc(5);
data++;
free(data);
```

Как себя поведёт программа с таким кодом? Будет ли освобождена память с нового адреса или вообще ничего не освободится?

Comment: Все рухнет (может не сразу, а при следующих malloc/free)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такое использование `free()` вызовет неопределенное поведение (undefined behaviour).

[Согласно статье на cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) ([русский автоперевод](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)):

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ptr does not equal a value returned earlier by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, or `aligned_alloc()` (since C11).

что собственно и получится в результате приведенного вами кода.
Значение `data` после выполнения

```
data++;
```

становится неравным тому, что было возвращено ранее в

```
char *data = malloc(5);
```

поэтому ожидать можно чего угодно, один и тот же код на разных платформах скомпилированный разными компиляторами может вести себя по-разному. Факт, что так делать точно не стоит :), и делать свой код зависимым от неопределенного поведения – дорога к страданиям.

Довольно велика вероятность получить следующее:

> ```
> *** Error in `XXX' free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000YYYYYY ***
> ```

однако, разумеется, негарантировано.

Answer (score 4):

Если по-простому, то функция `free` должна откуда-то знать, сколько памяти освобождать. На вход она получает только указатель, а значит на основании этого указателя функция вычисляет, сколько памяти нужно освободить. Нужную информацию где-то сохраняет `malloc`. Где именно и как уже зависит от реализации, стандарт не дает никаких указаний. Когда вы увеличиваете указатель, тогда `free` некорректно вычислит сколько памяти нужно освободить. Будет вызвана функция внутреннего менеджера памяти, и скорее всего программа упадет. Напомню, что обычно `malloc/free` не запрашивают и не отдают память обратно в ОС. Память запрашивается большим куском в ОС, а только потом `malloc` отдает из нее нужные фрагменты для программы.

Для примера я выполнил код ниже в компиляторе/среде Microsoft C++:

```
void testmalloc(int size)
{
    char *data = malloc(size);
    data -= 8;
    int* x = data;
    printf("%d\n", *x);
}

int main()
{
    testmalloc(16);
    testmalloc(64);
    testmalloc(256);
    testmalloc(1024);
    testmalloc(4096);
}
```

Вывод:

```
71
73
74
75
76
```

Как видно, среда запоминает какой-то индекс размером 4 байта по смещению -8 байт относительно адреса. Если вы сдвигаете указатель вперед на 1 байт, то функция `free` вместо нужного индекса получит какой-то мусор.

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть, как устроенны `malloc` и `free`. Я пробовал транслировать код с помощью `gcc` и ключа `-S`, чтобы увидеть ассемблерный код (`gcc -S main.c`), но в получившемся файле `malloc` вызывается инструкцией `call`, а как посмотреть, где написан код самого маллока - я не понял. В папке MinGW много объектных файлов в разных поддиректориях, но у них не "говорящие имена".

Comment: @Don2Quixote я боюсь там всё очень запутано будет. Я находил это: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=f7cd29bc2f93e1082ee77800bd64a4b2a2897055;hb=HEAD

Comment: @Don2Quixote а если не секрет - такой интерес вызван желанием написать свой аллокатор с блекджеком и...?

Comment: @AntonMenshov Нет, я просто задаюсь вопросами, на которые не могу найти ответы)